# Problem importing a module using importlib with Python in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, module, google-cloud-functions, python-importlib

I have a python script that dynamically imports modules so they don't need to all be loaded by hand. The line that does the actual import is

```
module = importlib.import_module(dirname)
```

Works fine locally.

When I deploy to Google Cloud Functions however, it can't find the module. I'm getting the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo/bar'
```

However, the `dirname` value which I fed into the function was actually `foo.bar`, as if GCP has converted the module structure into a directory structure. Does anyone know a workaround here? It won't work for my application to use `import` statements I need to use this variable based structure inside the class.

I was expecting the `foo/bar` module to load as it does on my local, but it didn't work. I tried this solution

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.insert(0, Path(__file__).parent.as_posix())
```

[from this github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-python/issues/92#issuecomment-1549153623)
in an attempt to normalize the directory structure but that didn't work either

Comment: I do not think your strategy will work in Cloud Functions. Nor do I think your strategy is a good one. You want a function to respond **quickly** because you pay for that CPU time. That means loading modules into the global namespace, initializing global variables, etc. during startup and not when a function is called. What benefit does your strategy offer?

Comment: Have you tried with `module = importlib.import_module(Path(__file__).parent / dirname)` ?

Comment: @JohnHanley This allows me to add modules simply by creating a directory in the file structure, then programmatically handling them in my class rather than having to update the code manually to look for the new module. This is an action I expect to do regularly, as this is a compiler program with multiple scrapers. I did it this way for maintainability. Could you suggest another approach that would let me programmatically add modules that might be better? Thank you

Comment: @RohitKharche I have not I will try that and update this answer thank you

Comment: @Brian Aderer Have you tried the above change ?

Comment: @RohitKharche yes that's basically what I was doing, dirname was a variable. The more I looked into it seems to be a file structure issue with GCP and since the dynamic import is important to script functionality I wound up just running it locally where it works fine. Thanks for following up!

Comment: Do you mean that your issue is resolved ? If so can you post that as an answer, so other's will also get help from this, if not then you can use \`module = importlib.import_module('foo.bar')\` line at the end of your tried solution.<br>